# can't send Email from Webservice written in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email

I wanna send an Email from my Webservice, written in vb.net, but I get an Timeout.
What is wrong?

```
                    Dim toaddress As MailAddress = New MailAddress("xxx")
                    Dim fromaddress As MailAddress = New MailAddress("yyy")
                    ' The structure for MailMessage(from, to)
                    Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(fromaddress, toaddress)

                    message.Subject = "I have sent you a message from a program!"
                    message.Body = "Hello World!"

                    Dim messanger As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtpxxx", 995)

                    messanger.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "password")
                    messanger.EnableSsl = True

                    messanger.Send(message)
```

Comment: You need to add the `To` and `From` to the `MailMessage` object

Comment: What is "smtpxxx"? Are you sure port 995 is the one your SMTP service requires (port 587 is the usual one for SMTP - 995 is usually for POP)?

Comment: yes 995 is true, it works in my mail on my mac.
smtp is an private mail.xxxx.li
the TO in the MailMessage Object is readonly. and it is set here:
Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(fromaddress, toaddress)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing many things wrong and some of the information you have given are not clear enough. host name and port names have to give properly. it chooses which mail service you are using, from your code it is not correctly provided, so i will give a snippet that uses gmail to send mail. please go through this and make changes as per your `SmtpHost`.

```
     Try
        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password")
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        e_mail = New MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress(txtemail.Text)
        e_mail.To.Add(txtemail.Text)
        e_mail.Subject = "Email Sending"
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
        MsgBox("Mail Sent")
    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
    End Try
```

This link help you to find the [smtp.Server and Port numbers](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html), you can use this [thread](https://support.mailpoet.com/knowledgebase/lists-of-hosts-and-their-sending-limits/) for check the limitations of smtp.servers